# How high does my reputation need to be in order to pick the best outcome in Citadel:Volus Ambassador?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The mission Citadel: Volus Ambassador has an option that adds the Volus Bombing Fleet, a good war asset bonus or saving the colony which gives you ... well ... a warm feeling inside.

It's also possible to get both using a paragon or renegade choice **if your reputation is high enough**.

What is the threshold to make this choice possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need to be at the third rank of the reputation to be able to convince Din Korlak to send his fleet to save the Volus' One.

This will cause Turian Sixth Fleet to suffer -10 points, but you'll get voolus Bombing Fleet which value is 75 points. Unless you Zaed is alive, where there will be no penalty.

Source: [List of maximizing War Assets thread on Bioware forum](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/347/index/10119654)

Answer (score 0):

Its not your reputation.. You have to have Zaeed's dlc and made him survive the suicide mission in ME2

Comment: mariemo's answer indicates that it's possible to do it on reputation.  So let's assume that we had the dlc and survived the mission in ME2, how does this affect the war assets and requirements?